# How do I force my PHP Symfony project to stay in dev mode?

Tags: php, symfony, development-environment

If I access `symfonyproject.local/app.php`, it uses the production environment. If I access `symfonyproject.local/app_dev.php`, it uses the dev environment. I want to develop and test quickly, so I need any URL to load app_dev.php.

But when I click a link in the dev environment, like `<a href='/users'>Link</a>`, it obviously loads `symfonyproject.local/users` and not the `symfonyproject.local/app_dev.php/users` that I need. How can I force clicking a link in dev environment to automatically stay in dev environment? Is there a feature that rewrites the all URLs or do I have to create it on my own?

Comment: if you use the twig functions (`path()` or `url()`) to render your links that should happen by default. Are you not using these functions?

Answer (score 6):

If you use the router to generate URLs then they automatically have `/app_dev.php/` in them. See [Symfony Twig Extensions - path()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path).

I personally don't use *app_dev.php* directly. I use a modified *.htaccess* that points to *app_dev.php* instead of *app.php*.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `url()` method for correct generated links

```
$this->url('@route');
```

Or faster way, you can change environment variable in file `app.php`, but I not recommend this way.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using something like this in your `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "YOUR DOCUMENT ROOT"
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    <Directory "YOUR DOCUMENT ROOT">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It will add a rule such that all requests will pass through `app_dev.php`

- Its just an alternative answer to those previously mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 3 you can force the system to run in dev mode by updating app.dev and change the following:

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);

to

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);

Then when you visit your site you will not have to pass app_dev.php in the URL.

For Symfony 4 you update the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `.htaccess` file in your `/web` folder of the Symfony installation.

You will see in several places in this file that it refers to `app.php`. Change this to `app_dev.php` and the entire project will default to dev mode everywhere!

Go go back to live mode, change it back to `app.php`

Comment: I would suggest against editing the .htaccess in the project directly, as you might accidentally commit this change to your source control, and it might end up on the production server this way.

Comment: The argument about accidentally commiting changes to the server holds for every suggestion on this page. The .htaccess is safer than most, because it's easy to exclude from git and directory listings. And if you push directly from your dev enviroment, you will be getting worse problems than this!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to modify the front controller so it uses environment variables instead of a hard-coded environment and debug mode. This way of working also completely mitigates the risk of accidentally deploying the dev front controller to your production server as an added benefit. I just delete `app_dev.php` from my project.

app.php

```
<?php

use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../app/autoload.php';

$env = getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'prod';
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') === '1' && $env !== 'prod';

if (!$debug) {
    require __DIR__ . '/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}

if ($debug) {
    Debug::enable();
}

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Now I just need to set the environment variable, which can be done with the Apache `SetEnv` directive in for example the virtual host config.

```
SetEnv SYMFONY_ENV dev
SetEnv SYMFONY_DEBUG 1
```

Answer (score -5):

Some good answers so far but I don't like fooling around with .htaccess.  Too much magic.  So I just:

```
cd web
mv app.php app_prod.php
cp app_dev.php app.php
```

If I need to flip back to production I just copy app_prod.php back to app.php.

Comment: The entire purpose of the .htaccess file is that you can configure one part of your server locally and easily. I would recommend making dev changes there rather than in the code.

Comment: But I am not making any code changes.  Just copying a file.  And of course if your web server does not use htaccess then the htaccess approach does not work well.  I blame the down votes on Clinton.